# How to add data source to Lookup Edit at run time?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, lookup, xtraeditors

I have 2 Lookup edits in my winform. If I select 1st Lookup edit, need to add data source to 2nd Lookup edit based on what i selected in value in 1st Lookup edit. This all function can be done at run time.

This code i use currently for 1st Lookup edit and If i select any Item from 1st Lookup edit I need to fill / attach data source to 2nd Lookup edit.

How to complete my task ?

```
private void lookupedit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        object row = lookupedit1.Properties.GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue(lookupedit1.EditValue) as object;

        memoedit1.Text = (row as DataRowView)["BFlatNo"].ToString() + ", " + (row as DataRowView)["BLocation"].ToString() + ".";
        memoedit2.Text = (row as DataRowView)["DFlatNo"].ToString() + ", " + (row as DataRowView)["DLocation"].ToString() + ".";

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your current code, so that we can see how we can fix that

Comment: Hi Sriram I Updated my question please verify it.

Comment: You've got the `row`, using that you can change `lookupedit1.DataSource` isn't it? Where you got struck

Comment: Hi, In my access database 2 tables available, in that 1st table consist of name, address and some more details. In second table consist of number of product by a customers, both table consist of reference numbers & unique number. Now If i select customer name (Lookup Edit1) from table one eg "Jhon" now I need to add data source to Lookup edit2 that consist of reference numbers of that particular Customer. eg. A single Customer consist of 2 or more references on different date. how to bind that in code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
yourLookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource = //Your List or DataTable
```